# Android Camera: Unboxing of 'characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING)' may produce NPE

Tags: java, android, android-camera2

I'm implementing `Camera2`, and i'm getting the following warnings (I couldn't reproduce any of the "npe" that may occur) when I'm setting up the camera outputs (I get my code from a sample of [google](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic)) the following line give me the following warning:

> "Unboxing of 'characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING)'
>   may produce NPE."

```
 for (String cameraId : manager.getCameraIdList()) {
      CameraCharacteristics characteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId);

      if (characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING) 
           == CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING_FRONT) { //THESE LINE IS WHERE THE WARNING APPEARS
           continue;
         }
   ....
```

Does someone knows how to inspect this in a proper way in order to catch this in case it happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are comparing it with a primitive `int`, and `characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING)` is probably returning an `Integer` which is an object. What happens is that you will have

```
Integer integer = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING);
if (integer.intValue() == CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING_FRONT) {

}
```

if `integer` is null, you will get a `NPE` accessing `intValue()`